# Spotfire - Custom Expression with marked rows

Tags: spotfire

I would like to know if it is possible to create a custom expression to change only marked rows like :

```
If(Marked([Filter]="Out")) else [Filter]="In"
```

Thanks for your help.

Regards, Laurent.

Comment: what are you trying to do, in the end? I don't think what you've asked is possible but maybe we can find a solution to your use case.

Comment: I have a barchart (1), I select a column (2), I click on a button(3), I would like change in my table only marked rows (4). It's a calculated column. I had find a code to update a calculated column and it work. But i would like update only marked rows.

Comment: sorry, more questions :) are you using the Web Player interface or the Analyst client? and what kind of database is your table coming from (file or linked data)?

Comment: Thank you niko, but i give up and do something else. ;)

Comment: Basically you can't do that, instead tags should be used such cases. (make your selection, attach a tag for selected items, then you can filter on that tag).